# How do I disable my CD/DVD drive?

Tags: udev, hardware, optical-media

I'd like to disable my CD/DVD drive so that it doesn't spin up every time I select Save in my Kate editor, or select a file-accessing action in other applications. The spinning up just delays what I'm doing, and I'm not even using the DVD drive.

I want to leave the CD in the drive, and not have it spin up.

I found a website that said a udev rule will definitely disable the drive.

So far, I've tried the following 2 rules (separately), but neither of them disable the DVD drive (it still spins up - even when not mounted):

```
ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="PIONEER_DVD-RW_DVRTD11RS_SAC1009942", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

```
KERNEL=="sr0",ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", RUN+="/bin/touch /home/peter/udev-rule-ran"
```

The `RUN+` in the second instance, creates my test file "udev-rule-ran", so this tells me that my rule file is being executed, and that the rule line is being run.

### My Question:

Could you tell me what I should be doing to definitely disable the darned DVD drive? I also want to be able to enable the drive again on the occasions that I need it.

### Supplementary Details:

I'm trying very hard to write a udev rule to disable my CD/DVD drive. I've tried various non-udev methods to disable it but none of them work.

There is no loaded module¹⁾ for the drive that I can unload, so I can't use that method to disable the drive.

*¹⁾ So I think the driver must be compiled into the kernel.*

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you keep a CD in the drive? If you're certain that you don't want to use it, why have it there?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Not sure of OP's reason, but I keep mine loaded because it's old (dinosaur) and locks shut if closed empty, even briefly. Not sure of the process, udev or otherwise, but wouldn't `umount`ing it solve the problem? If so, just add `noauto` to the fstab options.

Answer (score 0):

To the fine Administrator from OP:

I'm sorry that I can't leave a comment because I'm a guest. So could I humbly
ask if you would add my comment below to the page please. Thanks so much.

Thanks Hans-Martin Mosner and Gypsy Spellweaver. Sorry but yes I do have a
reason why I want to keep the CD in the drive. Re Gypsy: After umounting the CD,
the drive still spins up when I select a file-accessing action in an
application. For example, in Kate, when I select File/Save, the Save window
appears, then the DVD drive spins up, presumably offering itself for possible
use. I checked, and the CD remains unmounted.

Comment: if you register your account, you'll have access to your own question ...

Answer (score 0):

I have also fought with `udisks`/`udisks2` in the past (because may CD is behind a cheap SATA-IDE bridge, which goes into a reset loop if an audio CD is present when `udisk` tries to poll), and it's really difficult to disable it reliably. It's not properly documented, some stuff changed from udisks to udisks2, etc.

I ended up making a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules` to circumvent the original `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks2.rules` with contents:

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="udisks_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="udisks_end"
KERNEL=="ram*", GOTO="udisks_end"
ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_NOPOLICY}="1"
ENV{UDISKS_DISABLE_POLLING}="1"

########

LABEL="udisks_end"
```

This is still not 100% effective, under some conditions `udisks2` still gets invoked. For whatever reason.

If you find a more reliable and selective way to disable it, I'd be interested to know.